What low code/no code process is optimal for moving data from MS Fabric Notebook to Data warehouse
I'm working through different architecture setups within the MS Fabric layer and building out some processes to standardize on.
An area I am getting stuck on is what is the optimal way to move data from a notebook in a multi step pipeline to a datawarehouse.
The basic premise is:
Raw data is ingested into a lakehouse from disparate sources.
Data is transformed using a data gen2 set of transformations and placed in a silver lakehouse.
Data from the silver lakehouse is ingested into a notebook and is processed through a set of analytical components in Python or R.
From there, it seems like there are limitations in driving the processed data frames into a gold warehouse for final storage and last mile consumption.
Trying to determine if the optimal model would be to use code in the notebook to push directly into a data warehouse or to push data back into a different silver lakehouse table and then add another pipeline component to go from lakehouse to warehouse or something else?
The concern with the code side is that it is more difficult for our data citizens to construct pipelines of data flows.
There doesn't appear to be a good transition way from Notebook to Data Warehouse.

The good thing is you can write a T-SQL INSERT INTO ... SELECT pulling data from a lakehouse and inserting it into the warehouse, and the performance is reasonable as well - see this example
CREATE TABLE [research_warehouse].[dbo].[cases_by_continent]
AS
SELECT 
FROM [cases_lakehouse].[dbo].[bing_covid-19_data] cases
INNER JOIN [reference_warehouse].[dbo].[bing_covid-19_data] reference
ON cases.[iso3] = reference.[countrycode];

The problem then can be, how do you trigger that T-SQL query, especially if your silver transformations are in Fabric notebooks. I was dealing with that in this question - how to load from a lakehouse to a warehouse in a python notebook.
In short, you need to make an ODBC connection from the notebook and that will take some setup (see the answer to that question).
To make this lakehouse - warehouse transfer easier, I built it into my Fabric library. Using that library, your code can be something like
import bifabrik as bif

# service principal used for authentication
bif.config.security.servicePrincipalClientId = '56712345-1234-7890-abcd-abcd12344d14'
# secret of the service principal stored in Key Vault
bif.config.security.keyVaultUrl = 'https://kv-contoso.vault.azure.net/'
bif.config.security.servicePrincipalClientSecretKVSecretName = 'contoso-clientSecret'
bif.config.destinationStorage.destinationWarehouseName = 'WH_GOLD'
bif.config.destinationStorage.destinationWarehouseConnectionString = 'dxtxxxxxxbue.datawarehouse.fabric.microsoft.com'

# run this SparkSQL in the lakehouse and save it as 
# [WH_GOLD].[dbo].[HolidayCountsYearly] in the warehouse
bif.fromSql('''
SELECT countryOrRegion `CountryOrRegion`
,YEAR(date) `Year` 
,COUNT(*) `PublicHolidayCount`
FROM LH_SILVER.publicholidays
GROUP BY countryOrRegion
,YEAR(date)
''').toWarehouseTable('HolidayCountsYearly').run()

Detailed setup and config options here (and if something doesn't work, let me know, thx :))
